# Is it possible to make *.js and folders visible in theme-editor

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, directory, visual-editor

I just created a file `test.js` in the folder of my own child-theme. Unfortunately it is not visible in the Theme editor. How can I make it visible? And is it possible to make folders visible?

Comment: Its not possible to edit js files present inside theme through theme editor. It the way WordPress restrict editing JS for themes.

Comment: You should not use the built in code editor at all. That thing is a horrifically bad idea-- like working on an airplane while it is in the air.

Comment: Well, I like the buit-in editor, because it allows you to quickly change and test the scripts. I found a way to make the files visible: http://fenon.de/javascript-datei-im-theme-editor-sichtbar-machen/ . There is no other way, I'll answer my question.